# .net memory management in my app (datagridviews)

Tags: .net, memory, garbage-collection, c++-cli

I was wondering if I'm missing something.  I have a pretty complex app, but the core of it is this:

I query a database, which returns 10k-ish entries.

I store those entries in a custom business object.

Those objects are added to a BindingListView, and bound to a datagridview.

Now, over time, (40+ queries), my memory usage continually rises, to the point where I get an OutOfMemoryException at around the 42nd query.

I'm wondering I'm not deleting something or have a memory leak.  I'm 100% sure every single business object is properly deleted before the next query starts.  I really do think all my memory (1.5gig at the time the app dies usually), are all datagridview rows.

To note:  I'm using .net 2.0, visual c++ running VS2008

Comment: Turns out the problem was in my datagridview.  Changing its datasource wasn't releasing the used resources.  Setting it to null before changing the source was triggering the garbage collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to wrap ALL your db calls and data readers in using statements to make sure they are disposed of properly

Comment: My database calls are very indirect, they're managed by an entirely different app.  To my current one, its actually just read from shared memory through windows, which is properly freed after reading.

Comment: If that's the case and it is being disposed of then you're simply reading way too much data from the db into memory, is it possible for you to get "pages" of data? By that I mean if on the screen you only display 100 rows in the grid then read 200 into memory or so and then update when you need to?

Comment: I think I figured out out, its the damn DataGridView's bindings.  Calling BindingSource->SourceLists->Clear() is not releasing its references to the data objects.  I'm deleting the bindingsource and rebuilding it each time I run my query, and I believe its working.  I've run 100 consecutive queries, and am still taking up <200mb ram.

Comment: Ahh yes BindingSource.... and C# is supposed to be garbage collected.... I had my run ins with BindingSources before, I totally understand

Comment: `using` won't help, finalizers will run when memory gets low.  Something's causing these massive object trees to still be reachable, probably via a reference hidden inside a delegate subscribed to an event.

Comment: I think BindingSource has a private method called RemoveAll that actually does the correct disposing of resources, I remember having to use Reflection to clear up an issue with this or HttpListener (Don't really want to load VS with 1m lines of code to figure out which it was), might be the latter so I'm not sure.

Comment: I made sure I unsubscribed from every event referencing my object specifically.  I'm going to try the "RemoveAll" call, see if that is the "correct" way to do it.  Setting BindingSource.datasource = null; BindingSource.datasource = new(BIndingListView()) is hoekey (sp?) and I don't like it. But, it works...

Comment: Yeah setting it to null may force the call to the garbage collector to come in and pick it up.